# Review Updated Google Play Developer Distribution Agreement

Tags: android-studio

We’re continually striving to make Google Play a positive experience for both our developers and our users. For this reason, we’ve introduced the following changes to the Developer Distribution Agreement (DDA)

How to solve the problem